# Angular ngx-translate does not share app translation within lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngx-translate

I have an app in angular and I am using ngx-translate for the i18n.
I would like to have a translation that is shared for all the modules (lazy) of the app and a specific one per module.
This is what I have:

-- app.module.ts -->

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/core/', '.json');
}
@NgModule({
...
imports: [
...
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
...
exports: [TranslateModule],
```

-- app.component.ts -->

```
    ...
    constructor(
        private translate: TranslateService
      ) {
        translate.setDefaultLang('es');
      }
```

-- lazy.loading.module.ts -->

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/login/', '.json');
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
...
TranslateModule.forChild({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
      isolate: true
    }),
```

-- lazy.loading.component.ts -->

```
...
constructor(
    protected translate: TranslateService,
    protected currentLanguageService: CurrentLanguageService
  ) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('es');
  }
```

The messages of the login module are translated using the pipe translate:

```
{{ 'login.or' | translate }}
```

but the core messages remain without translation.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!